# Error: shared_preferences_platform_interface-1.0.3/pubspec.yaml: Missing the required "name" field

Tags: flutter, local-storage, sharedpreferences

I am getting the following errors on [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package while performing `flutter pub get` I had also opened an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51403) on Github a month ago but, I wasn't lucky to get any proper solution.

```
Error on line 1, column 1 of ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_platform_interface-1.0.3/pubspec.yaml: Missing the required "name" field.
Running "flutter pub get" in numbertrivia...                            
pub get failed (65; Error on line 1, column 1 of
../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_platform_interface-1.0.3/pubspec.yaml: Missing
the required "name" field.)
```

Comment: did you try `flutter clean` then `flutter pub upgrade`?

Comment: @Hamed same error on performing `flutter pub upgrade` **Error on line 1, column 1 of ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_platform_interface-1.0.3/pubspec.yaml: Missing the required "name" field.
Running "flutter pub upgrade" in numbertrivia...                        
pub upgrade failed (65; Error on line 1, column 1 of
../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_platform_interface-1.0.3/pubspec.yaml: Missing
the required "name" field.)**

Comment: you could try an older version, mine works fine at version ```shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4```

Comment: @xion same error on `shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve errors on cached packages, you can use the command `flutter packages cache repair`. It forces every used package to be downloaded again, just in case it has been corrupted.

Similarly you can look up the exact path in cache for a specific package in the `.packages` file of your project. Then, you can delete it and run `flutter packages get`.

This should solve your problem. You can learn more about common errors and how to fix them [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues).

Comment: Thank you it helped :D

Comment: That didn't help me at first. But it helped me to find the path to the local packages. After I deleted the broken packages, `rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/<path to broken package>`, `flutter pub get` worked.